# Show that for any random variable $X$, and any $a > 0$, $P(|X| > a) \leq {EX^4 \over a^4}$.

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Show that for any random variable $X$, and any $a > 0$, $$P(|X| > a) \leq {EX^4 \over a^4}.$$

Maybe I need to use Markov's Inequality, but I don't know how.

Comment: Hint: $|X| > a$ iff $|X|^4 > a^4$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$1_{\{|X|>a\}} \leq \left| \frac{X}{a} \right|^4 1_{\{|X|>a\}} \leq \left| \frac{X}{a} \right|^4. $$ Now integrate both sides.